# Incluir body en peticion http.post

Tags: flutter, dart, xmlhttprequest

necesito pasar estos argumentos dentro del body de mi peticion http.post pero me da el siguiente error.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Invalid request body "{....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Cliente_Lista xmlns="http://jpa.alicante.org/">
      <usuario>usuario</usuario>
      <password>contraseña</password>
    </Cliente_Lista>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'''
```

Aqui os dejo mi codigo, ahora no me da el error del body pero si me da un error 500. En postman me funciona correctamente pero es porque en el header me falta "Content-Length", pero cuando lo pongo en flutter me lanza un error formatexception invalid radix-10 number.
Estoy totalmente perdido. Gracias

```
class ClientsService extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _baseUrl =
      Uri.parse('http://jpaalicante.no-ip.org/eNotasCRM_Cliente.asmx');
  final _body = ''' 
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
          <Cliente_Lista xmlns="http://jpa.alicante.org/">
            <usuario>usuario</usuario>
            <password>password</password>
          </Cliente_Lista>
        </soap:Body>
      </soap:Envelope>
  ''';

  final List<Client> clients = [];
  late Client selectedClient;

  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

  bool isLoading = true;

  ClientsService() {
    this.loadClients();
  }

  Future<List<Client>> loadClients() async {
    this.isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    final resp = await http.post(
      _baseUrl,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        "SOAPAction": "http://jpaalicante.org/Cliente_Lista"
      },
      body: _body,
    );

    print(resp.statusCode);

    return loadClients();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: No vemos cuál es la petición que genera ese error. Por favor inclúyela. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Perdon @Alfabravo pero soy nuevo en esto. Te dejo mi codigo a ver que puede estar ocurriendo.